# Binding String using MATCH AGAINST in query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, binding

Binding to prepare statement using mysqli is working fine when I'm using query like this

```
if ($stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT url, title, fulltxt FROM links WHERE id = ? ")){// do something}
```

but it's nott working when I'm using this query

```
if ($stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT url, title, fulltxt FROM links WHERE MATCH(fulltxt)  AGAINST(?) ")) {//do something}
```

What is the right way of using `MATCH() AGAINST()` with a question mark in query for binding value.

Comment: That looks correct, what happens, errors? If you pass the value in statically does it work?

Comment: it gives no error. (i haven't turn giving error off)

Comment: Have you turned error reporting on? Do you get `prepared failed` or just no results returned? Does executing query on DB directly work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

New full code based on pastebin:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php
            error_reporting(-1);
            // here the db details

            $query = "%".$_GET['q']."%";

            // Connecting to the server and selecting database
            $dbh  = new mysqli($host, $user, $password,  $database);

            if ($dbh->connect_error) {
                echo 'Unable to connect to database '. $dbh->connect_error;
            } else {
                // run query to select records
                if ($stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT url, title, fulltxt FROM links WHERE fulltxt LIKE ?")) {
                    // binding user-supplier input $class to the parameter as string
                    $stmt->bind_param("s", $query);
                    // executing the statement
                    $stmt->execute();
                    // binding the table columns Name and Email to the $Name and Email parameters respectively.
                    $stmt->bind_result($URL, $TITLE, $FULLTXT);
                    /* fetch associative array */
                    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                        echo $URL. ' -- '. $TITLE. '<br />';
                    }
                } else {
                       echo "Prepare failed: (" . $dbh->errno . ") " . $dbh->error;
                }
            }
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

The problem was fixed by replacing MATCH with LIKE and concatenating the variable with percentage characters on both side.

Comment: else{
        echo "Prepare failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }        I used this code but it returens no error.

Comment: you have to use $dbh not $stmt! Have you also turned error reporting on? by adding error_reporting(-1); at the start of the php code?

Comment: Please check my full code. here it is. http://pastebin.com/8SGJfBQp   I don't know why after adding else {
    echo $dbh->error;
} its giving this error "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in... "

Comment: the code you have in the pastebin still says $stmt->error. which is not correct.

Comment: I thiln this is the correct solution. But sitll not working on my hosting. after removing error_reporting(-1); not giving any. error. thanks for attemptiing. I shall try the code on another server. may be there have some problem in current hosting

Comment: you should leave error reporting on, if you remove it the error is still there. it just doesn't show. Is it still the same error when exactly using my code?

Comment: but I am wondering why this is working perfectly. http://pastebin.com/RqCe1p1C  this is the same code just I use "ID" to find result in query.

Comment: Yes I tried your script with and without error_reporting line. I think there may be another problem. Like "MATCH AGAINST" gives zero results when it founds the searching key in more than 50% row. I think something happening like this because it giving no error and no result

Comment: Why are you using MATCH anyway? match has all kinds of options which i don't think you're aware of: read: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html
just do the same as id and use = it works perfectly fine on strings, i'll edit the code in my answer to show this.

Comment: Try the full code from my answer again, i made a mistake editing. i think this should work.

Comment: finding with id is working fine. I tried to make a simple search engin. I found almost every search script tutorial on internet are sql injectable. So i thought to binding data to prevent sql injection

Comment: if you use prepared statements correctly (which you do ^^) you can just use = safely. as long as you bind the parameters using "?" and not insert it manually in the query. the code i have given you is secure against sql injection.

Comment: Its still not working with WHERE fulltxt = ?. because fulltext row got some full articles. I tried to search with LIKE %?% But that doesn't work too. Thank you very much for your help. Forget it I shall use another script. If you know about any simple searching script please tell me. And thanks again

Comment: don't use another script. this one is perfectly fine. i didn't understand what you wanted to accomplish, if you want LIKE you have to add % signs to the variable, not the query, see updated answer.

Comment: Oh yes! Now its working perfectly with LIKE. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No problem :) if i may make one suggestion, try and keep error_reporting in the code. it just makes errors visible, it doesn't make new ones. any errors that might show up are already there which means they need fixing ;) anyway, good luck!

Answer (score -2):

This has happened to me a few weeks ago, the solution is to try to escape a string variable with \ (Backslash). It looks like this:

```
$where = "'\"{$some_variable}\"'";
```

And then, bind the param with $where variable:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT url, title, fulltxt FROM links WHERE MATCH(fulltxt) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $where);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Why would the quotes need to be escaped? Can you please explain?

Comment: Because I want to use that " (quotes) which means double quotes in MySQL MATCH Full-Text using Boolean mode only match literal values to retrieve all the rows that contain for example the word "Sky Sailing".

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand. What does it have to do with binding the data in the prepared statement? It sounds to me like you had a requirement to add double quotes to your string which has nothing to do with binding the data. Are you sure this is a solution to the problem stated in the question?

Comment: I'm trying to binding the data with double quotes without escape the string but that won't work in mysqli prepare statement, so I came to this question to try fix it then suddenly it works with escape the string variable. Sorry, but I'm trying to help here.

Comment: It's good that you are trying to help. I am only trying to understand your solution. I have never heard of the data impact of the data on the way that prepared statement binding is done. In fact, the data can't impact the binding in any way. Your solution might be helpful but it lacks an educational part to it. You should explain why the escaping is needed (which by the way has nothing to do with mysqli as I see it)

Comment: Thank you, I will try my best in the future to explain more about my solution.